# get values from an html table

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write a website that calculates the inverse matrix. I have a table. I also wrote a function to resize the table. I need the entered values to be read into a two-dimensional array (arr), and I can use this array as a function argument (PrintMatrix(arr)). I'm new to this and I'm not very good at it

My table:

```
<div class="row col-sm-12" id="block1">
  <div class="well well-sm col-xs-12 col-lg-11">
      <h4><b>Inverse Matrix</b></h4>
   
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <form class="form-inline" autocomplete="off" id ="mainForm">
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">Size:</span>
                      <select id="mrow" onchange=" CreateTable(); " class="form-control">
                          <option value="2">2x2</option>
                          <option selected value="3">3x3</option>
                          <option value="4">4x4</option>
                          <option value="5">5x5</option>
                          <option value="6">6x6</option>
                          <option value="7">7x7</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              
              </form>
        
              <form autocomplete="off" id="form1">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-1">
                          <h3 class="text-center">A</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6" id="divA">
                          <table class="table_matrix" id="matrixA">
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><input id="a11" type="text" /></td>
                                    <td><input id="a12" type="text" /></td>
                                    <td><input id="a13" type="text" /></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><input id="a21" type="text" /></td>
                                    <td><input id="a22" type="text" /></td>
                                    <td><input id="a23" type="text" /></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><input id="a31" type="text" /></td>
                                    <td><input id="a32" type="text" /></td>
                                    <td><input id="a33" type="text" /></td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                      </div>
                  </div>
            
              </form>
              
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

function for resizing:

```
function CreateTable() {
        var element = document.getElementById("matrixA");
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        var columnA = document.getElementById("mrow").value;
        var rowA = document.getElementById("mrow").value;
        var doc = document;

        var fragment1 = doc.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i = 1; i <= rowA; i++) {
            var tr = doc.createElement("tr");
            for (var j = 1; j <= columnA; j++) {
                var td = doc.createElement("td");
                td.innerHTML = "<input id='a" + i + j + "' type='text'/>";
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            fragment1.appendChild(tr);
        }
        var table1 = doc.createElement("table");
        table1.className = "table_matrix";
        table1.id = "matrixA";
        table1.appendChild(fragment1);
        doc.getElementById("divA").appendChild(table1);
    }
```

Also, i have it, but it only works for a 3x3 table and if you change the size of the table, you still get a 3x3 array. Also, for some reason, the array values are "undefined"

```
var table = document.querySelector('#matrixA');
  var tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
  var tr = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
  let tableArray = new Array();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  tableArray[i] = new Array();
  for (let j = 0; j < tr[i].children.length; j++) {
    tableArray[i][j] = (tr[i].children[j].children.value);
  }
  }
  console.log(tableArray);
```

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: @user1599011 get the values from the table and create a two-dimensional array

Comment: That's not a question; that sounds like your objective. What have you attempted to achieve said objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function that returns a matrix with the input of your user, based on your code, you can use a more simple approach using the `id`s that you've set, with something like this:

```js
function getInputByMatrix() {
    const rows = document.getElementById('mrow').value;
    let input = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        input[i-1] = [];
        for (let j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
            input[i-1][j-1] = document.getElementById(`a${i}${j}`).value;
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

For what concern your attempt to create this function, you get only `undefined` values because you are attempting to get the `value` property on a `HTMLCollection` object; indeed the `children` read-only property returns, as you can see from the following quote from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children), a live collection of children elements.

> The read-only children property returns a live HTMLCollection which
> contains all of the child elements of the element upon which it was
> called.
>
> An HTMLCollection which is a live, ordered collection of the DOM
> elements  which are children of node. You can access the individual
> child nodes in the collection by using either the item() method on the
> collection, or by using JavaScript array-style notation.
>
> If the element has no element children, then children is an empty list
> with a length of 0.

To obtain the desired behavior, in this case, you could just access the first element of the collection, that is `tableArray[i][j] = (tr[i].children[j].children[0].value);`.

Also, when resizing the matrix, you forgot to insert a `tbody` tag, so your function will always fire an exception when the size of the matrix has been changed.

```js
var fragment1 = doc.createDocumentFragment();
    // There is no <tbody>!
    for (var i = 1; i <= rowA; i++) {
        var tr = doc.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 1; j <= columnA; j++) {
            var td = doc.createElement("td");
            td.innerHTML = "<input id='a" + i + j + "' type='text'/>";
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        fragment1.appendChild(tr);
    }
    var table1 = doc.createElement("table");
    table1.className = "table_matrix";
    table1.id = "matrixA";
    // Appending to the <table> tag the fragment composed by <tr> <td> ... </td> </tr>
    table1.appendChild(fragment1);
    doc.getElementById("divA").appendChild(table1);
```